# How do I use savepoints in SQL Workbench/J with Redshift?

Tags: amazon-redshift, sql-workbench-j, savepoints

Is it possible to recreate the following in redshift sql workbench?

```
create table test as 
select top 10 * from core_data;
savepoint sv;
delete from test
where name like 'A%';
savepoint sv2;
delete from test
where name like 'B%';
rollback to sv;
```

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name yes, ty, I made the edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Redshift doesn't support `Rollback` to `Savepoints` at all by any means. Hence you can't do with workbench as well.

See here list of all the [unsupported](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_unsupported-postgresql-functions.html) `PostgreSQL` functions by Redshift. It includes **savepoints** as well.

If you execute `rollback to savepoint` query to Redshift like,

```
rollback to savepointexample;
```

You will see following error.

> ERROR:  SQL command "rollback to savepoint sv3;" not supported.